# CRM 2013 Form Libraries

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm-2013, eventhandler, custom-function

I am trying to utilise the Dependant Option Set functionality in the SDK. I have created the 2 JS files I need and I put them into the Form Libraries and Event Handler sections of the form properties and saved the form. 
I did not publish the form but when I go back into the form properties they are no longer there.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like somebody else customized the form, saved the changes and published them before you could publish the form. Form customizations, save and publish is almost like importing a solution. If somebody else publishes the form before you get a chance to, the customizations are overridden.

Just like the last solution import always wins, if you do not publish your changes, they will be overridden by another simultaneous publish.

Comment: I am the only person working on this form though and its happening again today. On top of that I have tried to create a workflow to alter a couple of fields but workflow but I set the properties of the alter line in the wf and again, when I go back in it has all gone. What is going on??

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a browser issue. Works fine in IE